# How to send mail with attachment in GWT?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

I would like to know if there is a way to send an email with attachment file with GWT.
I managed to send a simple email without attachment, but I am having a problem when I try to add a file.

The problem is that "FileUpload" don't give the fullpath of the file

it seems for safety reasons it is impossible to retrieve the full path of the file from the client.
Is there another way keeping the logical server in gwt client?

*My code*

**Client side:**

```
FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
// cannot retrieve the full path
String fileAttachment = upload.getName();
```

**Server side:**

```
public void sendMail(String sender, String[] recipients, String subject, String message, String fileAttachment) {  
        try {  
            ...(init)           

            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();


                   //   =>  fileAttachment need full path
            DataSource source = 
              new FileDataSource(fileAttachment);

            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(
              new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileAttachment);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(multipart);

            // Send
            Transport.send(msg);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you're going to have to save the uploaded file on the server and then reference the path to the saved file in your FileDataSource.  Actually, it may be possible to use the I/O stream to feed the data as the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually **upload** the file to the server.

The easiest way in GWT is to put your `FileUpload` (and all your form input widgets) in a `FormPanel`; it has the drawback of making error handling (and response handling from the server) more difficult though.

An alternative, in recent browsers, is to get the `File` object (**not** a `java.io.File`, a JS object) out of the `FileUpload` and upload it using `XMLHttpRequest` (possibly coupled with `FormData` to also send the other form values). In GWT, that means using JSNI (it might be possible to use the `Elemental` library too), and really know the innards of what you're doing.

In any case, you won't be able to use GWT-RPC to talk to your server **and** send the file at the same time.

Comment: Thks for your help, can you provide me a sample working code for uploading the file using gwt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259680/how-to-transfer-a-file-from-client-to-server-in-gwt-using-fileupload/9259847#9259847